# Which one of these two mantras is more powerful?

Tags: scripture, shiva, mantras, shakti

This was new for me when I heard the mantra:

> Aum Namah Shakti Shivay

Normally we chant:

> Aum Namah Shivay

My questions:

1. For knowledge sake I would like to read references from our scriptures where '**Aum Namah Shakti Shivay**' has been used.
2. Which of these two mantras is more powerful?

Comment: There can not be any mantra like the first one as thats wrong sanskrit.

Comment: @Partha Wrong sanskrit means?

Comment: sanskrit is a language which follows strict grammatical rules.

Comment: @Partha so what's the grammatical error in that mantra?

Comment: shakti can not remain that way.

Comment: @Partha I'll leave that part for scholars.

Comment: Om namah Shakti Shivaya - this seems to be man made mantra .. such mantras do not hv any power ..the other one is however a famous Vedic mantra @Just_Do_It

Comment: @Rickross check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvDLxii2esE

Comment: Ok, yes it does not seem to be a valid Mantra to me, seems to be a manufactured mantra.. @Just_Do_It

Comment: @Rickross are you 100% sure about it or is it just a guess? Just asking :)

Comment: We can not be 100% sure about mantras, coz Lord Shiva himself says that there are as many mantras as there are dust particles on the earth and only I know all of them, nobody else does .. but still I feel this to be a manufactured mantra @Just_Do_It

Comment: Never heard first mantra Om namah shakti shivaya.. Seems like grammar is also wrong.  But second mantra Panchakashari occurs in Sri Rudram which is part of Yajurveda.

Comment: It can be correct Sanskrit if `ShaktiShiva` is one word formed by a tatpurusha samaasa. However the authenticity is something else.